# django-registration create_user() unexpected keyword

Tags: django, django-registration, django-profiles

I am trying to create a custom profile to add additional fields to `django-registration`. Here is the code I have so far --

in `models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

and in `settings.py`

`AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'myproject.Profile'`

However, I am getting the following error when I try to use create_user(). Here is what happens when I type it into the interpreter --

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> User.objects.create_user(first_name='tom',last_name='smith',email='ts@gmail.com',password='hello')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: create_user() got an unexpected keyword argument 'first_name'
```

What am I missing in order for `create_user()` to recognize these new columns? Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a number of things you're doing wrong here

Firstly, these aren't fields on the User model, they're on the Profile model. So it shouldn't be surprising that the User manager method doesn't recognise them. You'll need to define a User object in the normal way with create_user, then define the Profile instance using that user.

Secondly, `create_user` doesn't take all the field names as keyword arguments - it only takes [username, email and password](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user). Again, you'll need to set the other fields yourself afterwards.

However, I don't understand at all why you've defined these particular fields. They are all available in the [built-in User model](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#fields). In particular, you should definitely not be defining your own password field, unless you also write some code to store the password as a hash rather than as plain text.

Comment: then how to store the first name and last name if we cannot use create_user ??

Answer (score 1):

```
username, first_name, last_name, email, password = kwargs['username'], kwargs['first_name'], kwargs['last_name'], kwargs['email'], kwargs['password1']
        user = User(username=username, email=email, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
```

that's the solution